Creating VendorBill in Netsuite using REST API
I am trying to create a Vendor Bill on Netsuite using REST API, when create expense line items I cannot find a way to add Tax Code or Tax Rate? I've gone through all their documentation and cannot find anything that helps.
Here is the current snippet for the expense line items I have:
"expense": {
        "items": [{
                "amount": 111.11,
                "memo": "Line item 1 desciption",
                "account": { 
                    "id": "111"
                },
                "custcol_prj_name": {
                    "refName": "11111"
                }
            }]


Here is a screenshot in netsuite of the columns I need to add.
Netsuite image
I tried using the  taxDetails field on the actual vendorBill and that didn't change anything, I tried taxDetailsReference and it did nothing either. I want to autopopulate the Tax Code and Tax Rate so it can calculate tax and give the correct bill total with tax.

I think it's not possible , that value came with the item definition. If you need to change Tax Code you will need create another item with the another tax code
